# Excel - Sumifs referencing a cell with an array

Tags: arrays, excel, reference, array-formulas, sumifs

I am trying to write a sumifs formula which contains an array in the criteria but the array is in another cell which the sumifs formula will be referencing.

For example, I want to achieve this result, where I am summing column B if column A equals 5003 and 5009:

`=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,{"5003","5009"}))`

However, instead of writing out "{"5003","5009"}" in the formula, I want this part to be referencing another cell which contains this array. For example, I want to do something like:

`=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D1))`

Where D1 equals:

`D1="{"5003","5009"}"`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: D1 does not hold an array it holds a string that looks like an array.  You can split the values into individual cells then do: `=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D1:D2))`  Otherwise you will need to parse the string to create the array.

Answer (score 1):

Came up with a solution to this based on an earlier answer...

I was referencing a cell that contained multiple criteria I wanted considered in my SUMIFS formula. Couldn't get that cell to behave like an array until I used the TEXTSPLIT formula. Wrote my two criteria in the cell being referenced using a semicolon delimiter:

```
Criteria 1;Criteria 2
```

Assuming that text was in cell D1, values in column B, and criteria range in column A, I wrote my formula like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,TEXTSPLIT(D1,";")))
```

This cracked the code for me. End formula is much more complex, but this is the basic principle I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

In `D1` if your criteria's are comma separated then you can use `FILTERXML()` to build an array for `SUMIFS()` criteria. Try below

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($D$1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

If you data exactly looks like `"{"5003","5009"}"` in `D1` cell then try below formula.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($D$1,CHAR(34),""),"{",""),"}",""),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your formula, but FilterXML does not appear to be an available formula for me. Upon googling, I found that Mac does not support this formula. Is there an alternative for Mac users?